# If $f$ is $\mathcal C^1$, i.e. $f(x)=a+bx+o(x)$, does the rest is $\mathcal C^1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in \mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$. Then $$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+o(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+x\varepsilon (x),$$
where $\varepsilon (x)\to 0$ when $x$ to $0$. Now, can I say that $\varepsilon (x)$ is $\mathcal C^1$ or not really ?

Comment: If $f(x)=|x|^{3/2}$, then $\epsilon (x)=|x|^{3/2}/x$ which is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Look at

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x = 0\\
x^3\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & x \neq 0
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is $\mathcal C^1$ with $f(0) = f^\prime(0)=0$. However $\varepsilon$ (that is easy to calculate!) is not $\mathcal C^1$.

Comment: Your function $f$ is not  $\mathcal C^1$: we have $f'(0)=0$ and $f'(x)=2x \sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ for $x \ne 0$. Therefore $f'(\frac{1}{n \pi})=(-1)^{n+1}$, hence the sequence $(f'(\frac{1}{n \pi}))$ is divergent.

Comment: @Fred Would the problem be solved if $x^2$ is replaced by $x^3$?

Comment: You're right. Thanks. A typo in the exponent that I correct.